# React, use reducer. Problemas para eliminar un recurso contra la base de datos

Tags: reactjs

Estoy practicando con react, y ya he visto un poco de redux. Y tambien el hook de use reducer, para simplificar el tema de la configuracion de redux. 
Estoy probando algo contra la base de datos. en este caso eliminar un usuario. el usuario se elimina correctamente pero tengo que actualizar la pantalla para que el cambio se vea reflejado. no estaria sucediendo que automaticamente al apretar el boton de eliminar, este usuario desaparece de la interfaz.
Agradezco cualquier ayuda!.

ABMUSUARIOSTATE

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";
import AbmUsuariosContext from "./abmUsuariosContext";
import AbmUsuariosReducer from "./abmUsuariosReducer";
import clienteAxios from "../../AxiosConfig/axios";
import Swal from "sweetalert2"
import {
  OBTENER_USUARIO_ELIMINAR,  
  ELIMINAR_USUARIO_EXITOSO,
  ELIMINAR_USUARIO_ERROR,
} from "../../Types/index";

const AbmUsuariosState = (props) => {
  const initialState = {
    usuarios: [],
    usuarioEliminar: null,
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AbmUsuariosReducer, initialState);


  //obtener usuario a eliminar
  const obtenerUsuario = id => {
     dispatch({
        type : OBTENER_USUARIO_ELIMINAR,
        payload : id
     })
     eliminarUsuario(id)
  }


  //funcion para eliminar un usuario
  const eliminarUsuario = async (id) => {



    try {
      await clienteAxios.delete(`/api/usuarios/eliminar/${id}`);
      dispatch({
        type: ELIMINAR_USUARIO_EXITOSO,
      });
      Swal.fire("Deleted!", "Your file has been deleted.", "success");
      console.log("Usuario eliminado")
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response);
      dispatch({
        type: ELIMINAR_USUARIO_ERROR,
      });
    }
  };


  return (
    <AbmUsuariosContext.Provider value={{usuarios: state.usuarios,usuarioEliminar: state.usuarioEliminar,obtenerUsuario,eliminarUsuario }}>
      {props.children}
    </AbmUsuariosContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AbmUsuariosState;
```

ABMUSUARIOREDUCER

```
import {
  OBTENER_USUARIO_ELIMINAR, 
  ELIMINAR_USUARIO_EXITOSO,
  ELIMINAR_USUARIO_ERROR,
} from "../../Types/index";

export default (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case OBTENER_USUARIO_ELIMINAR:
        return{
            ...state,
            usuarioEliminar : action.payload
        }
    case ELIMINAR_USUARIO_EXITOSO:
      return {
        ...state,
        usuarios: state.usuarios.filter(
          (usuario) => usuario.id !== state.usuarioEliminar
        ),
        usuarioEliminar: null,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

InfoUsuario

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import AuthContext from "../Context/Authentication/authContext";
import AbmUsuariosContext from "../Context/ABMUsuarios/abmUsuariosContext";
import Swal from "sweetalert2";
import clienteAxios from "../AxiosConfig/axios";

const InfoUsuario = () => {
  const [usuarios, setUsuarios] = useState([]);

  //Aca se tendrian que mostrar todos los usuarios que esten logueados
  useEffect(() => {
    const consultarApi = async () => {
      const url = "https://localhost:44378/api/usuarios";
      const consulta = await clienteAxios.get(url);
      console.log(consulta.data);
      setUsuarios(consulta.data);
    };

    consultarApi();
  }, []);

  const history = useHistory();

  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { cerrarSesion } = authContext;

  const abmUsuariosContext = useContext(AbmUsuariosContext);
  const { eliminarUsuario, obtenerUsuario } = abmUsuariosContext;

  const logOut = () => {
    cerrarSesion();
    history.push("/");
  };

  const confirmarEliminarUsuario = (id) => {
    Swal.fire({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
      icon: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
      cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
      confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.value) {
        //mandarlo al action
        obtenerUsuario(id);
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Info usuario</h1>
      <button onClick={logOut}>Cerrar Sesion</button>

      <h1>Libros:</h1>

      {usuarios.length === 0 ? (
        <h1>No hay libros....</h1>
      ) : (
        usuarios.map((libro) => (
          <div key={libro.id}>
            <ul>
              <li>{libro.nombre}</li>
              <button onClick={() => confirmarEliminarUsuario(libro.id)}>
                Eliminar libro
              </button>
            </ul>
          </div>
        ))
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default InfoUsuario;
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que se puede extraer del código, estás llamando al backend para que actúe en la base de datos pero posteriormente no modificas los datos que tienes almacenados en tu app. En ese caso deberías usar la ID devuelta por tu función para buscar ese usuario en tu array de datos y eliminarlo o, en su defecto, hacer otra llamada a la api para extraer los usuarios almacenados en la BDD.

Comment: Hola que tal? ahora cambie el codigo y estoy usando redux puro(sin usar el hook use reducer). ahora cuando elimino un usuario, llega a mostrarse el mensaje que ese usuario se elimino(antes eso no pasaba) pero tengo que actualizar la pagina para ver los cambios. los cambios en el state los hago en el reducer usando el metodo filter de los arrays para que me devuelva esa coleccion de usuarios salvo en el que hice click para eliminar